# Detecting unsafe const reference binding in C++

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-warnings

I've just spent quite a lot of time debugging an obscure memory corruption problem in one of my programs. It essentially boils down to a function which returns a structure by value being called in a way which passes it into an object constructor. Pseudocode follows.

```
extern SomeStructure someStructureGenerator();

class ObjectWhichUsesStructure {
  ObjectWhichUsesStructure(const SomeStructure& ref): s(ref) {}
  const SomeStructure& s;
}

ObjectWhichUsesStructure obj(someStructureGenerator());
```

My reasoning was: `someStructureGenerator()` is returning a temporary; this is being bound to a const reference, which means the compiler is extending the lifetime of the temporary to match the place of use; I'm using it to construct an object, so the temporary lifetime is being extended to match that of the object.

That last bit turns out not to be the case. Once the constructor exits, the compiler deletes the temporary and now `obj` contains a reference to hyperspace, with hilarious results when I try to use it. I need to explicitly bind the const reference to the scope, like this:

```
const auto& ref = someStructureGenerator();
ObjectWhichUsesStructure obj(ref);
```

That's not the bit I'm asking about.

What I'm asking about is this: my compiler is gcc 8, I build with `-Wall`, and it was *perfectly happy* to compile the code above --- cleanly, with no warnings. My program ran happily (but incorrectly) under valgrind, likewise with no warnings.

I have no idea how many other places in my code I'm using the same idiom. What compiler tooling will detect and flag these places so that I can fix my code, and alert me if I make the same mistake in the future?

Comment: I'm unaware of any gcc flag for this. The best defense is to be proactive. I'm not saying never have references as class members. But, every time you want a reference as a class member, think long and hard about it, and make sure -- double check, and triple check -- that you have all ducks lined up in a row.

Comment: It's quite rare that a reference as a class member makes much sense, so you might want to search for such things.

Comment: the class can never be constructed anyway since its constructor is private

Comment: Don't use reference members (especially const) and check with address sanitizer/valgrind.

Comment: You might want to look into static analyzers, e.g. [clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or compiling your program with `-fsanitize=memory` (which I think gcc 8 supports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reference binding *does* “extend lifetime” here—but only to the lifetime of the **constructor parameter** (which is no longer than that of the temporary materialized anyway).  `s(ref)` isn’t binding an *object* (since `ref` is, well, already a reference), so no further extension occurs.

It’s therefore possible to perform the extension you expected via **aggregate initialization**:

```
struct ObjectWhichUsesStructure {
  const SomeStructure &s;
};

ObjectWhichUsesStructure obj{someStructureGenerator()};
```

Here there is no constructor parameter (because there is no constructor at all!) and so only the one, desired binding occurs.

It’s worth seeing why the compiler doesn’t warn about this: even if a constructor does retain a reference to a temporary argument, there are **legitimate situations** where that works:

```
void useWrapper(ObjectWhichUsesStructure);
void f() {useWrapper(someStructureGenerator());}
```

Here the `SomeStructure` lives until the end of the statement, during which time `useWrapper` can make profitable use of the reference in the `ObjectWhichUsesStructure`.

At the expense of *forbidding* the valid use cases above, you can have the compiler trap the problematic case by providing a **deleted constructor** taking an rvalue reference:

```
struct ObjectWhichUsesStructure {
  ObjectWhichUsesStructure(const SomeStructure& ref): s(ref) {}
  ObjectWhichUsesStructure(SomeStructure&&)=delete;
  const SomeStructure& s;
};
```

This might be worth doing temporarily as a diagnostic measure without having it be a permanent restriction.

Comment: Aha, yes, && is the trick: my object is a protocol adapter, and is intended to exist on the stack with a strictly shorter lifetime than the object it's referring to. So, it makes no sense to bind it to something which is an rvalue. Deleting the && constructor causes all the occurrances of this to show up as errors, which is exactly what I want. I would be happier if I could globally disallow rvalue refs everywhere except when I explicitly ask for them, though.

Comment: @DavidGiven: I realize that this barely qualifies as “tooling”; unfortunately, you can’t turn off parts of the language (partly because the compiler would have to know when it was looking at someone else’s code that should be allowed to use them).